# GUID validation RegEx fails new line character

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to validate a GUID in PHP with the following line.

```
$case_number = "088169ed-7a9d-4f78-b999-170971247642\n";
$GUID_validation_RegEx = '/^[A-Fa-f\d]{8}-[A-Fa-f\d]{4}-[A-Fa-f\d]{4}-[A-Fa-f\d]{4}-[A-Fa-f\d]{12}$/';
print(preg_match($GUID_validation_RegEx, $case_number));
```

It returns `1 (true)`

I've narrowed down the problem to the following ...

`^[A-Fa-f\d]{8}-[A-Fa-f\d]{4}-[A-Fa-f\d]{4}-[A-Fa-f\d]{4}-[A-Fa-f\d]{12}$`

```
                                            ^^^ these A-F (if I remove them the new line does not match)
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Use `\z`, or `$` with `/D` modifier.

Comment: Thanks! Working now